# NameError: name 'message' is not defined Discord Python

Tags: python, discord

So i am a **Beginner** programmer so i dont really know alot about python i was trying to get the member count for my server using a bot but i dont really know about ctx here is my entire code

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord.ext
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"{client.user} Has connected to the discord api!")
@client.event
async def on_message():
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
@client.event 
async def on_message(ctx):
  if message.startswith("!MemberCount"):
    print(ctx.guild.member_count)
client.run(discordtoken)
```

pls help me with this question

Comment: `name 'message' is not defined` - isn't that self explanatory? How is Python supposed to know what `message` is if you don't tell it what it is anywhere?

Comment: also be aware that you can't define `on_message` twice, the second definition probably overwrites the first one

Comment: So, where is `message` defined in your code then?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please re-read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We do not care about your level of experience. We care about a clearly asked, specific question. We cannot ["help you"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236) in general, and we cannot help you with a question that you do not actually *ask*. If you want help understanding the error message, then you should a) explicitly ask a question about the error message, and b) [try to do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: If you really can't figure something out after your best research and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) efforts, then [isolate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the problem as best you can and [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) when there is an error (copy and paste, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and format as code).

Comment: Because of the kinds of problems I see in this code, it comes across that you are trying to copy and paste little bits of code from elsewhere, or at least trying to mimic them without actually understanding what they mean. Programming does not work like that. It is important to learn the fundamentals. Before trying to create a Discord bot at all, it is better to reach the level where you can quickly solve a problem like this yourself, with a clear understanding. To start this process, try to follow tutorials on Python itself, rather than any specific project.

Comment: figured it out just need to remove on_message and start using @client.command

Answer (score -1):

```
users_num = 0
@client.command()
async def comm(ctx):
    general = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name='Vibing')
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name='Ongoing Matches')
    channels = category.channels
    for channel in channels:
        print(channel.members)
        for member in channel.members:
            users_num = users_num + 1
     await comm.send(ctx)
```